# Connecting to apache server using SSH and PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, ssh

I have read the php manual for ssh connections.  I am still not clear as how to connect securely to my server over ssh using php.  I have searched stackoverflow and still don't understand.  Can someone give me an explanation with functions used to connect to a apache server?

Comment: You can't connect to an apache server using SSH. You can only connect to a SSH server.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois  An SSH server?  Are there secure connections for apache similar to ssh?

Comment: What are you actually wanting to accomplish, @Fuel?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Do you know where I can find information on that?

Comment: The whole internet is full of informations about SSL. But what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Securely connect to a website hosted on a home PC.

Comment: It is possible to use SSH to create a tunnel through which you can make HTTP requests. It's a pretty unusual thing to want to do though.

Comment: @Fuel What do you mean by "securely connect", what do you want to do after that? Do you just want to connect to a website secure and then browse it like what we're doing on Stack Overflow? Then set up SSL and then just connect to your website over HTTPS.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois  An encrypted connection to a website to add comments, images, etc.  Would I use OpenSSH?

Comment: @Fuel an encrypted connection usually is provided by a website when they have SSL certificates installed on their server. Are you asking how to install SSL certificates on your server so users can browse and comment securely?

Comment: @Fuel No, OpenSSL or GnuTLS. Must likely Apache has already OpenSSL as module installed, so you just need a SSL certificate and configure apache. Same if you use Nginx.

Comment: @JasonBassett  Yes, how to install SSL certs would help.

Comment: @Fuel have you already purchased the SSL certs for your domain(s)?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois  Thanks for that information.  I already have Apache installed.  I'll look for the OpenSSL module.

Comment: @JasonBassett No.  Where do I purchase them?

Comment: You can purchase them from almost any domain registrar. I personally use [NameCheap](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/single-domain.aspx) and purchase the $9 Single Domain SSL cert.

Comment: @Fuel You can either purchase one, or generate them yourself with OpenSSL (any browser will throw a warning then :)) or get one from http://startssl.com

Comment: He's already confused about the situation, let's just keep it simple for him please :) @CharlotteDunois

Comment: @JasonBassett and CharlotteDunois  Thanks to both of you.

Comment: I've added my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015692/connecting-to-apache-server-using-ssh-and-php-mysql/28015798#28015798) below. If you feel as though my help was useful, please tick the check mark :) @Fuel

Comment: @JasonBassett  SSL is incorporated in the packet before data is sent over the network correct?

Comment: SSL encrypts any data sent to or from that server to be encrypted using various algorithms to protect the content from being intercepted. @Fuel

Comment: @JasonBassett Why did you delete your answer? ^^