# Moving to SSL: Do I need to change my code

Tags: php, ssl

I'm completely new to the idea of having SSL on a website I develop, but the possibility of it being needed for the project I'm working on is becoming more and more real.

I have code, all (on the server side) written in PHP. I want to make sure that when I move to the production server, it will all work just as I expect.

1) Do I need to change any code that has been written for standard HTTP

2) Do I need to set an http header, saying that it's secure

3) How can I implement a sorta version of SSL on my testing server

4) What does a certificate do for me? If I'm okay with having the user (which should be like one person) ignore the untrusted warning, can I go without it?

Your help and assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: You won't be OK without a trusted certificate. Save yourself the time and expense of rework, pay the money now.

Comment: You dont need to change your code, the webserver takes care of connection. If you want to use SSL locally, check if OpenSSL is installed. If you use xampp or similar it's already installed.

Comment: Without testing, you won't know for sure. For example, linking from a secure site to insecure http resources such as image or scripts will/may cause warnings. Also look into setting the [SecureFlag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) on your cookies to prevent them from being sent on non secure requests, otherwise your session cookie will leak if you accidentally link over to an insecure link.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I use Apache2 on Ubuntu 14.10. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I don't exactly use http resources. Everything that's linked is using a relative path, like 'resources/google.png'

Comment: @ilarsona Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015692/connecting-to-apache-server-using-ssh-and-php-mysql/28016054#28016054